# Flutter CachedNetworkImage doesn't work, loading images again when scrolling up to bottom or bottom to up

Tags: flutter, dart, lazy-loading, image-loading

I'm trying to work with cached images. I followed [CachedNetworkImage](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images)  but it doesn't work. Please help me if any other solution available in flutter

[Here is video of my issue](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ageru-f4fc9.appspot.com/o/video%2FScreenrecorder-2019-09-24-09-09-41-648.mp4?alt=media&token=ac287aa7-ee2c-4382-854f-753186426b71)

When I scrolled list from up to bottom or bottom to up the images are gone and reloaded again

Code

```
        ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                       placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
                            imageUrl: productList[position]["images"]
                            ["post_image1"],
                            height: 180,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ))
```

Comment: I have read somewhere that this plugin is not so effective right now.

Comment: Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CachedNetworkImage works fine for me.

Run your app on a simulator / emulator then you can see if the images have been cached.
Note that the image size makes a big difference (you don’t want them more than 100K and hopefully < 50K) as even if they are cached, each time they have to be re shown in the UI they have to be decoded. Looking at your video it looks like it takes a long time for the to load initially (which is either a slow internet or large files), then once they are loaded, then you still get the decode time (but that is a lot shorter than the initial download time).

In summary, make sure the images are of a sensible size for use in a mobile app.